# StructureMap Exception 202 No Default Instance defined (Version 2.61) - Error Not Consistent

Tags: c#, structuremap

I am getting "No Default Instance defined for TestRequestRepository" error for structureMap. Although this error is not consistent and frequent but it does appear at times.

Below is the sample code snippet i am using, please let me know what could be the cause of this "In-Between" error.

### Global.asax

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BootStrapper.Bootstrap();            
    }
}
```

### Bootstrapper class

```
public class BootStrapper : IBootstrapper
{
    public void BootstrapStructureMap()
    {
        StructureMap.ObjectFactory.Initialize(x => x.AddRegistry(new StrcutureMapInitialization()));
    }

    public static void Bootstrap()
    {
        new BootStrapper().BootstrapStructureMap();
        //new AutomapperInitialization();
    }

    public static void Dispose()
    {
        //Imp: This calls the Dispose on all HTTP context based instances
        ObjectFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects();
    }
}
```

### StrcutureMapInitialization Class

```
public class StrcutureMapInitialization : Registry
{
    public StrcutureMapInitialization()
    {
        For<ITestUnitOfWork>().HttpContextScoped().Use<FD.DAL.Test.Context.TestEntities>()
            .Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is("name=TestEntities");
        For<ITempUnitOfWork>().HttpContextScoped().Use<TempEntities>()
            .Ctor<string>("connectionString").Is("name=TempEntities");

        For<IDatabaseTypeRepository>().HttpContextScoped().Use<DatabaseTypeRepository>();
        For<ITestRequestRepository>().HttpContextScoped().Use<TestRequestRepository>();
        For<ITestProviderContainer>().HttpContextScoped().Use<TestProviders>();
    }
}
```

### TestFactory Class

```
public static class TestFactory
{       
    public static ITestProviderContainer GetTestContainer()
    {
        return StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ITestProviderContainer>();
    }

    public static ITestRequestRepository GetTestRequestRepository(ITestUnitOfWork testUnitOfWork, ITraceManager traceManager)
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        parameters.Add("unitOfWork", testUnitOfWork);
        parameters.Add("traceManager", traceManager);
        ExplicitArguments explicitArguments = new ExplicitArguments(parameters);

        return StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ITestRequestRepository>(explicitArguments);
    }
    public static ITestRequestRepository GetTestRequestRepository(int uId)
    {
        return StructureMap.ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ITestRequestRepository>();
    }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue. The issue was becuase there were multiple modules involved in this application and one of the module was calling a seperate strucutre map configuration from its constructor. So once the constructure of that module gets called, it overrides the earlier strucutre map defination.
So after putting all the structure map configuration in Gloabl.asax file, it started working fine.

Thanks for help.

Regards,
maanoj